# Defining equations with a constant

Tags: c

I am trying to define a constant that would have the following in it

```
ch[co].gold < 10000*100
```

how can I make it, something like

```
define x = ch[co].gold < 10000*100;
```

so that every time I write

```
if (x) {say(cn,"You need 10 000 gold coins");}
```

Or that is not possible?

Comment: Yes this is C indeed

Comment: Yes, it's called a boolean expression - just change "define" to a suitable type, e.g. `bool` or `int`. I recommend picking a [book from this list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/253056) and doing some reading if you want to learn C properly.

Comment: Thank you everyone, that notation threw me off, was a dumb question but yet something that is i am unfamiliar with in C. Thanks.

Comment: @Night there's a tradeoff here: you can type less now and scratch your head more later ... or type a little more now and keep a clear head in the future :-)

Answer (score 2):

Function:

```
int x(int val) {
    return (val < 10000 * 100);
}
```

Usage

```
    // ...
    if (x(ch[co].gold)) {
        printf("You need 10 000 gold coins.\n");
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: `x()` could have a better name, for example `enoughgold()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my solution

```
struct s {
    int gold;
};

const int co = 2;

struct s ch[] = {112,2321,3234};

#define x() ch[co].gold < 10000*100

int main(){
if (x()) {

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This one takes the cake. Nicely done, however what i posted is an excerpt from a code, ch[co].gold extracts an int from a structure, and just compares it to 10000*100. So simply asking how and if it is possible to simplify that comparison down to one character instead of typing it out (or ctrl c + ctrl v in that manner)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
#define x (ch[co].gold < 10000*100)
```

Add this line of code before the place you use it, usually it's just below the `#include`s.
Conventionally, we use capital letters with clearer meanings instead of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is simply text substition performed by the preprocessor.

To do what you say you want use the following `#define`:

```
#define x ch[co].gold < 10000*100
```

Every time the preprocessor encounters the symbol `x` it will replace it with `ch[co].gold < 10000*100`.

I think that what you really want is to make it a proper function as suggested by pmg. It is a wiser choice.